# ggplot black and white

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

I have a plot obtained with ggplot2

```
ggplot()+geom_line(data=results,aes(x=SNR,y=MeanLambdaMin,group=rep),col="blue")+
  geom_line(data=results,aes(x=SNR,y=MeanA,group=rep),col="green")+
geom_line(data=results,aes(x=SNR,y=VarA,group=rep),col="red")+
  geom_line(data=results,aes(x=SNR,y=VarB,group=rep),col="black")+
facet_wrap(~ rep, as.table=T)+xlab("SNR")+ylab("")
```

The result is good 
[image]

Unlikely I have to print it in black and white. 
What is the best thing to do?   Is there any option which optimize the color for a black and white versione?

here there is a reproducible example

```
results=data.frame("SNR"=1:30)
results$MeanA=results$SNR^2
results$VarA=results$SNR*2
results$VarB=results$SNR^(1/2)
results$MeanLambdaMin=1:30
results$rep=sample(x=1:3,size=30,replace=T)

ggplot()+geom_line(data=results,aes(x=SNR,y=MeanLambdaMin,group=rep),col="blue")+
  geom_line(data=results,aes(x=SNR,y=MeanA,group=rep),col="green")+
geom_line(data=results,aes(x=SNR,y=VarA,group=rep),col="red")+
  geom_line(data=results,aes(x=SNR,y=VarB,group=rep),col="black")+
facet_wrap(~ rep, as.table=T)+xlab("SNR")+ylab("")
```

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example? You should map color, line type, point type, to a variable and call it through an aesthetic.

Comment: use gray-black scaling

Comment: Can you please write the code. I am not expert with ggplot2.

Comment: @Donbeo You were asked to provide a reproducible example but then asekd a question instead of adding the reproducible example.  I assume that you may not know what that is.  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1000343) is info on doing so.  Basically if we don't have data to run it makes helping much more difficult and it makes understanding the solution more difficult.

Answer (score 7):

Your y values should be in one variable that correspond to the variable Species in this example. For instance:

Change linetype:

```
ggplot(iris)  + 
  geom_line(aes(Sepal.Length,Petal.Length,linetype=Species)) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

or

Change linetype and shape of points:

```
ggplot(iris)  + 
  geom_line(aes(Sepal.Length,Petal.Length,linetype=Species)) + 
  geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length,Petal.Length,shape=Species)) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: +1 - you could also vary the line width (good for if you want to highlight one line over others), and with only 3 you it wouldn't be impossible to construct three visibly distinct grey scales. Adding the points allows more areal gurth the distinguish different colors on the grey scale as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=results,aes(x=SNR,y=MeanLambdaMin,group=rep),col="grey0") +
  geom_line(data=results,aes(x=SNR,y=MeanA,group=rep),col="grey20") +
  geom_line(data=results,aes(x=SNR,y=VarA,group=rep),col="grey40") +
  geom_line(data=results,aes(x=SNR,y=VarB,group=rep),col="grey80") + 
  facet_wrap(~ rep, as.table=T) +
  xlab("SNR") +
  ylab("")
```

Now you have differences in black and white scaling :) play with the colors to look for the best combinations. You can see all colors by entering 'colours()'

also you can add + `theme_grey()` at the end of your plot code

Comment: If you use ggplot2 the way it is intended to be used, i.e., with a data.frame in long format, legends are produced by default. See the other answer.

Comment: @Donbeo try to use +legend()